# Accessing JSON values in D3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm trying to populate each group with a circle for "Forehand" / "Backhand" and "BH slice" but i'm having difficulties accessing these values. I have nested the elements in a way that the "Direction" is the Key so the related values will eventually influence the position and the size of each circle.

In a way it is similar to https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data the matrix example I guess but the data structure is different ?

JSbin of the current code here: http://jsbin.com/gahul/1

I have the following data:

```
   var JSONdata = [
            {
                "Direction": "Crosscourt",
                "Total": 118,
                "Forehand": 75,
                "Backhand": 41,
                "BH slice": 2
            }, {
                "Direction": "Down_middle",
                "Total": 50,
                "Forehand": 34,
                "Backhand": 9,
                "BH slice": 7
            }, {
                "Direction": "Down_line",
                "Total": 21,
                "Forehand": 8,
                "Backhand": 11,
                "BH slice": 2
            }, {
                "Direction": "Inside_out",
                "Total": 118,
                "Forehand": 25,
                "Backhand": 5,
                "BH slice": 0
            }, {
                "Direction": "Inside_in",
                "Total": 9,
                "Forehand": 9,
                "Backhand": 0,
                "BH slice": 0
            },
        ];
```

And the following d3 code:

```
                var query1 = d3.nest()
                  .key(function(d){
                        return d.Direction;
                      })
                  .sortKeys(d3.ascending)
                  .entries(JSONdata)

                var h = 420;
                var w = 500;

                var svg = d3.select("body")
                  .append("svg")
                  .attr("width", w)
                  .attr("height", h);

                var group = svg.selectAll("g")
                  .data(query1)
                  .enter()
                  .append("g")
                  .attr("class", function(d){ return d.key })

               var pop_directions = group.selectAll("circle")
                  .data(query1)
                  .enter()
                  .append("circle")
                  .attr("r", 30 )
                  .attr("cx", 100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the values of your new object are in an array with one element, which you have to adress, for instance:

```
d.values[0].Forehand
```

gives you the forehand-value, while you can access your key-value by

```
d.key
```

see http://jsbin.com/hakamoga/1/edit for a simple example using the forehand-value as radius and title.

Comment: Aha, makes sense! Thanks Herbert!